# How to restrict output of iw dev wlp3s0 scan?

Tags: arch-linux, configuration, wifi

I am trying to configure a wireless network on a newly installed Arch Linux. The command `iw dev wlp3s0 scan` gives information about all the found networks. I only need the information about my SSID.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have wifi around here to check, but I believe `iw dev IFACE scan` starts each section with a non-indented line and indents all subsequent lines. So you can treat a non-indented line as a section break.

This is not very easy to parse with the usual commands, so you can do it in two steps. First insert an empty line between sessions. Then use awk's paragraph mode.

```
iw dev wlp3s0 scan | 
sed 's/^[^ \t]/\n&/' |
awk -v RS= '/^[ \t]*SSID: myssid$/'
```

Beware to quote any special characters in the SSID properly. If you're passing it as a variable and need to handle special characters safely, it's a little more work.

```
iw dev wlp3s0 scan | 
sed 's/^[^ \t]/\n&/' |
awk -v RS= -v target="$ssid" '{
    ssid = substr($0, index($0, "\tSSID:"));
    ssid = substr(ssid, 1, index(ssid, "\n"));
    if (ssid == target) print;
}'
```

Comment: thanks. But the two commands seem to be too complex. It's easier to execute `iw dev wlp3s0 scan | less` and find the SSID manually.